# Looking for plagiarism checking tools under Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for plagiarism checking tools that work under Ubuntu (12.04) like viper for Windows.

Are there any such tools?

Comment: You can check http://plagcontrol.com/

Comment: This question would be better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  Be that as it may, you might try [similarity-tester](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=similarity-tester&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) available in the universe repository.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a software recommendation and not well suited for this site.

Comment: I disagree - this question is on topic

Comment: I disagree with the disagreement:  **:-)** The only answers this attracts is for commercial tools and spam. @Zanna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you looking for tool exactly under ubuntu, if there are lot's of online plagiarism checkers, which are free or payed, where you can create your account, etc. Try this [plagiarism checker](https://unplag.com/), it's accurate, simple and fast, also it has free and premium versions, which depends on your needs.

Comment: thank you, Ella for your answer ... I already used the suggested site and i admit that it gave almost the desired result